# Space-Time complexity in variation of Dutch National Flag

Tags: python, time-complexity, space-complexity, dutch-national-flag-problem

A variation of the DNF is as follows:

```
def dutch_flag_partition(pivot_index , A):
    pivot = A[pivot_index]
    # First pass: group elements smaller than pivot.
    for i in range(len(A)):
      # Look for a smaller element.
        for j in range(i + 1, len(A)):
           if A[j] < pivot:
             A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
             break

# Second pass: group elements larger than pivot.

for i in reversed(range(len(A))):
    if A[i] < pivot:
      break
    # Look for a larger element. Stop when we reach an element less than
    # pivot , since first pass has moved them to the start of A.
    for j in reversed(range(i)):
       if A[j] > pivot:
         A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
         break
```

The additional space complexity is given as O(1). Is that because the swapping doesn't depend on the input length? And time complexity, given as O(N^2), is it so due to the nested loops? Thanks

Comment: Swapping doesn't create any extra space at all. You do have a bit of space for some other things—like `pivot`, the `range` and its iterator, `i`, etc.—and those are all pretty obviously constant. (Unless this is Python 2, in which case those range are linear…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The additional space complexity is given as O(1). Is that because the swapping doesn't depend on the input length?

No. Swapping, in fact, takes no extra space at all.

More importantly, you can't just look for one thing and say however much that thing takes, that's the complexity. You have to look over *all* the things, and the *largest* one determines the complexity. So, look over all the things you're creating:

- `pivot` is just a reference to one of the list members, which is constant size.
- a `range` is constant size.
- an iterator over a `range` is constant-size.
- the `i` and `j` integer values returned by the range iterator are constant size.<sup>1</sup>
- …

Since nothing is larger than constant size, the total size is constant.

> And time complexity, given as O(N^2), is it so due to the nested loops?

Well, yes, but you have to get a bit more detailed than that. Two nested loops don't necessarily mean quadratic. Two nested loops that do linear work inside the nested loop would be cubic. Two nested loops that combine so that the size of the inner loop depends inversely on the outer loop are linear. And so on.

And again, you have to add up everything, not just pick one thing and guess.

So, the first pass does:

- A plain list indexing and assignment, constant.
- A loop over the input length.

  - … with a loop over the input length
  - … with some list indexing, comparisons, and assignments, all constant
  - … which also breaks early in some cases… which we can come back to.

So, if the `break` doesn't help at all, that's `O(1 + N * N * 1)`, which is `O(N * N)`.

And the second pass is similarly `O(N * (1 + N * 1))`, which is again `O(N * N)`.

And if you add `O(N * N + N * N)`, you get `O(N * N)`.

Also, even if the `break` made the first pass log-linear or something, `O(N * log N + N * N)` is still `O(N * N)`, so it wouldn't matter.

So the time is quadratic.

---

<sub>1. Technically, this isn't quite true. Integers are variable-sized, and the memory they take is the log of their magnitude. So, `i` and `j`, and the `stop` attributes of the `range` objects, and probably some other stuff are all `log N`. But, unless you're dealing with huge-int arithmetic, like in crypto algorithms that multiply huge prime factors, people usually ignore this, and get away with it.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> The additional space complexity is given as O(1). Is that because the swapping doesn't depend on the input length?

As you are "just" swapping there is no new data being created or generated, you are just reassigning values you already have, thus why the space complexity is constant.

> And time complexity, given as O(N^2), is it so due to the nested loops?

True. It's a second order polynomial time complexity because you have two for loops nested.

You have a `break` in them, so in more favorable cases your time complexity will be below N^2. However, as big-O is worst case then it's ok to say it's of degree 2.